# solve second order differential equation numerically

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve this equation numerically and plot x[t],t relation.
x   ''   [t]     ==     -   [   (   (   (   Q   ^   2    -    2    m   ^   2   ) 
  (   2    m    t    -    Q   ^   2   )   ^   2    /    (
        2    m    ^   2    t   ^   3 (   t    -    2   m  )    (   m    t    - 
   Q   ^    2    )   )   )   /   (   2   )    ]    x   [   t   ]

Comment: What is `Q,m`? What have you tried? You probably want `NDSolve`.

Comment: Yes.Can I plot this DE by considering  Q=0.4 and m=1.I have chosen these two values arbitrary.

Comment: @Emlie What are the two initial/boundary conditions?

Comment: @Emlie Did you saw my answer?

Comment: Yes. I am working on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your differential equations.

1. Initial/boundary conditions are missing.
2. For numerical solution (which seems to be the only way to solve your ode), numerical values for the parameters `Q` and `m` are missing.
3. Your ODE, involves $\frac{1}{t^3}$, $\frac{1}{(t-2m)}$ and $\frac{1}{(mt - Q^2)}$, so for $t=0$, $t=2m$ and $t=\frac{Q^2}{m}$, we are facing $\frac{1}{0}$.

Here is a sample code for you to play with,

```
ode = x''[t] == -(((Q^2 -2*m^2)*(2*m*t - Q^2)^2/(2*m^2*t^3*(t - 2*m)*(m*t-Q^2)))/(2))*x[t];
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{ode, x[10^(-5)] == a, x'[10^(-5)] == b}, 
                         x, {t, 10^(-5), 10}, {Q, m, a, b}];
Plot[Evaluate[x[1, 1, 0, 10][t] /. sol], {t, 10^-5, 1}]
```